# User defined comparison functions for permutation tests in R (coin?)

Tags: r, permutation

I am trying to find a package that supports user defined comparison functions. For instance, I want to compare distributions on the basis of quantile values, and skewness.

Perhaps the `coin` package can help? But I'm struggling to figure out how to define a valid `ytrafo` function.

Snippet below is for a median test, how do I get more flexibility?

```
library(coin)
independence_test(mpg ~ cyl, 
                  data = mtcars, 
                  ytrafo = function(data) 
                    trafo(data, numeric_trafo = median_trafo)
                  )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an old version of the `bda` toolbox that has a function `perm.test` with this functionality.

```
install_version("bda", version = "3.2.0-3", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```